# Remove OPTION in a SELECT without a CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-select

**Question:**

I want to remove options in a select box which DO NOT have a specific CSS Class.

**Skill Level**

I am still learning jQuery, maybe will do for a long time.

**Synopsis:**

I have a select box:

```
<select id="MySelect">
    <option class="MyClass" value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    <option class="MyClass" value="four">four</option>
    <option value="five">five</option>
    <option class="MyClass" value="six">six</option>
    <option value="seven">seven</option>
</select>
```

*So I want these options two, three, five and seven to be removed.*

I can count all options:

```
alert('Options Count: ' + $('#MySelect option').length);
```

And options with the class:

```
alert('Options with class: ' + $('.MyClass').length);
// I think this will search the entire file for elements with this class. Is this so?
```

But I am not sure how can I remove the ones which *do not* have the class. I know there is a very simple solution, but I cannot figure out a concise way to do it.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('#MySelect option').not('.MyClass').remove()
```

You can also put the "not" test inside the selector, but that's often slower (though it probably would make no practical difference):

```
$('#MySelect option:not(.MyClass)').remove()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct answer. Both options work. I am going with the first one as it appears more logical.